# msdeploy (Web deploy) installation in a container

Tags: iis, containers, msdeploy, webdeploy, windows-container

I try to containerize a third party application running on IIS and Windows server. To do that, they supply to me a powershell script which is using Web deploy 3.

My problem is I can't install it, I always have this error code :

```
 MSI install return value for product 'Web Deploy 3.6 ... is '1603'
```

The version 2 is installing though, but it's the version 3 which is required. I've also tried to install it with chocolatey, but I have the exact same error.

Here the part of the Dockerfile causing troubles :

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore-insider:10.0.17093.1000
[...]
# Register dll (the web say this can solve the error)
RUN regsvr32.exe %windir%\syswow64\vbscript.dll /s
# Copy The msi installer for web deploy 3.6
COPY webdeploy.msi C:\\Temp\\webdeploy.msi
WORKDIR C:\\Temp
# Install all webdeploy features
RUN msiexec /i webdeploy.msi LicenseAccepted="0" ADDLOCAL=ALL /quiet /qn /passive /norestart
```

Please do note I'am using the insider version because I need the MSMQ feature which is not released yet (It's a proof of concept).

Is there any requirement needed by webdeploy that I don't know and which is missing in the container version ?

Comment: Does this manual step work if you execute them inside VM running servercore insider edition?

Comment: It works in a server 2012 R2 and on a 2016 (both with GUI). I'll try on the core version.

Comment: Does your issue happens on DockerFile which is on non insider image?

Comment: Both are insider images : The VM running the container and the container (I need the version 17093 of the kernel)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking if you use non Insider version of OS/Container does this issue happens or not

Comment: Well. I've just tried on the non insider version and it works (no containers), and it doesn't work without container on the insider version. I guess I'm trapped.

Comment: Well, that's the reason you have inside verions, they are incomplete and potentially have issues, so you need to file a bug

Comment: It looks like there is a new build in the insider program (17623). I'll try this first. Thanks !

Comment: It works with the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in the preview build (as mentioned by @Gregory Suvalian). Using the last one (17623) seems to correct the problem.